# GIT: Whats the Difference between a Pull Request and a Merge?

Tags: git, git-merge, pull-request

On services like Bitbucket and Github, one has the option to create a Pull Request and a Merge. What are all of the differences between the two?

Differences I currently know of:

- Ability to approve or reject request
- Ability to provide add a descriptive message with the request

Other than that it seems like a pull request is just essentially a merge.. correct?

Comment: see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22199432/pull-request-vs-merge-request

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Yes that is correct, the `pull request` on GitHub and Bitbucket is a request to merge two branches.

One of the use cases is to have a QA person who is not the developer review and approve the merge request.

Another use case is development on `master` branch is not allowed. A developer always develop on another branch. Once the development is completed, a pull request is created to merge into `master` branch.

Comment: I would add to this that, `merge`'s can be quite small level like if you were to create a feature branch on a dev branch and merge iterations of that feature one at a time back into dev but a `pull request` would be used for merging that feature on dev into the production branch. A kind of check & balance to make sure nothing goes catastrophically wrong when merging into production.

Answer (score 11):

A "pull request" is a request to an upstream repository to merge some changes into their code ("pull changes from my repository and add them to yours, please").  So it's not really like a merge at all -- it's a *request* to merge.

Comment: Pull request (on GitHub) and Merge request(GitLab) are meant for the same thing. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22199432/pull-request-vs-merge-request