# Configuring the workflow using git and bluemix so we can review changes before a merge

Tags: git, ibm-cloud

New to Bluemix and trying to understand how we best configure our workflow so that there is an opportunity to review changes on a branch before it is merged back in to the master.

As context we are used to using GitLab where we follow a fairly standard branching model with the following steps in the normal course of events:

1. Create a feature branch
2. Fetch that to my local git repo
3. Do some stuff
4. Add changes, commit and then push

It's at this point we have effectively an air gap that protects our master i.e. we raise a merge request that another dev will pick up, review the code and if everyones happy do the merge before deleting the branch.

I appreciate that the flow maybe slightly different but want to add in that gap before the merge. Is this possible?

Paul.

Comment: What do you mean when you say you want to "add in that gap before the merge"?

Comment: Hi @DavidDeutsch - I'm working with Paul at the moment. The 'gap' he is refering to is looking for Bluemix integrated git's equivalent to GitLab's "Merge Request" or GitHub's "Pull Request" features where there's a step between pushing to the Origin's feature branch and merging in to Master. This step is where a 'request' is sent to another team member to review the changes before making the merge in to Master. See here for the definition of the functionality we are trying to replicate: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29951658/1700309.