# How to Git push a 'commit by another user'

Tags: git, git-push

Problem: In a certain directory, Git push is restricted to very few users(User1). Other users(User2) cannot push their changes here.

Is there a way so that - the User2 commits the changes(git add + Git commit) in that dir,  then he provides the commit number to User1 and the latter does the Git push?

Can it be done?

Comment: There are several ways to transfer commits. User2 can mail his commits to User1 who then pushes them for example. So in short, yes. But I assume it should not be possible for User2 to add+commit in that "certain directory", when he is not able to push. It would be better if User2 clones his own repository and does his changes there.

Answer (score 2):

Usually, `User2` does the changes and commits them. Then, she provides these changes to `User1` who pushes the changes upstream.

The changes can be provided via various mechanisms:

- `User2` could [`git format-patch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-format-patch) them and send the patches to `User1` via E-Mail
- `User2` could use [`git request-pull`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6235379/520162) in order to format an E-Mail holding details for `User1` where she could find the changes (additional bare repo, direct read access to the machine of `User2`, ...)
- Domain specific mechanisms (i.e. [Github Pull Requests, Gitlab Merge Requests](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22199432/520162), ...)

Your requirement is not uncommon: lots of open source projects work just like this: while everybody could contribute changes, it's up to certain (trustworthy) people to integrate these changes into the actual project repository.

---

**Edit**
I'll provide some examples for how to use `git format-patch` or `git request-pull` here

1. Create patches for the last 3 commits you did:

   ```
   git format-patch -3
   ```

   This will create 3 patch files that you could send via E-Mail to somebody that is allowed to commit on the upstream repo
2. Create patches for all commits of the branch `my-new-feature` since you branched off from master:

   ```
   git format-patch master..my-new-feature
   ```

   This will take each commit you did in `my-new-feature` and create a patch from it. Again, send these patches to the maintainer.
3. Publish your changes to the maintainer directly from your hard disk (Windows):

   - Share your working directory with the maintainer (give her read access), say as `\\yourmachine\yourworkingcopy`. From now on, the maintainer could read the contents of the shared folder
   - Open up your console and let the magic happen:

     ```
     git request-pull origin/master file:////yourmachine/yourworkingcopy my-new-feature
     ```

     This spits out a ready made E-Mail text to the console that you could take and send to your maintainer.

Comment: Thank you. Can you provide an example please if possible?

Comment: @Mr.Bordoloi: examples added!