# Should I use git merge or pull requests?

Tags: git, github

**For example**, if I am working on a git/github repo alone and have two branch (master and develop) and I make some commits to develop branch.

So should I go for git merge or pull requests and what are their benefits

Comment: This is a common question, see some other discussion here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22199432/pull-request-vs-merge-request

Comment: I have read that question, but I was still in doubt that pull request should be used if you are working in a team.

Answer (score 1):

By creating pull requests, you have a proper logging of your merges, which you can monitor via the Pull Requests section in GitHub.
In the end, you end up merging your `develop` branch to the master.

Another approach can be, keep your master clean, and always work on the develop branch, and to push your changes to master, just `rebase`, and bring your both branches to level.